# typescript: get an key map from object with generic

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I want to get the key map from any object,

I've implemented the function,

but I can't make typescript happy,

what should I do without using `acc: any`

```js
const origin = {
  a: 1,
  b: 'string',
  c: () => {}
};

function getObjKeyMap<T>(obj: T) {
  return Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc, k) => {
 /* Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{}'.ts(7053) */
    acc[k] = k;
    return acc;
  }, {});
}

const keyMap = getObjKeyMap(origin);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell the type of object that `reduce` uses for accumulator.

```ts
const originObj = {
  a: 1,
  b: 'string',
  c: () => {}
};

function getObjKeyMap<T>(obj: T) {
  return Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc, k) => {
    acc[k] = k;
    return acc;
  }, {} as Record<string, string>);
}

// or


function getObjKeyMap1<T>(obj: T) {
  return Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc: Record<string, string>, k: string) => {
    acc[k] = k;
    return acc;
  }, {});
}

const keyMap = getObjKeyMap(originObj);
```

[TS Playground](https://tsplay.dev/PmLpam)

However, I bet this is not the best solution. I bet there is a way to write a function declaration like this:

```
function getObjKeyMap<T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T): Record<K, K>
```

Where Typescript automatically tells you that `getObjectMap({a: 1, b: 'string', c: () => {}}` returns `{a: "a", b: "b", c: "c"}`.

I think this is much better:

```ts
const originObj = {
  a: 1,
  b: 'string',
  c: () => {}
};

type KeyMap<T> = {
  [key in keyof T]: key
};

function getObjKeyMap<T>(obj: T): KeyMap<T> {
  return Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc, k) => ({...acc, k: k}), {} as KeyMap<T>);
}


const keyMap = getObjKeyMap<typeof originObj>(originObj);
```

[TS Playground](https://tsplay.dev/qWJbRW)

Comment: Rather than using `{} as T` can't you just specify what the accumulator is inside of reduce's type arguments?

Comment: Yes, if you see the first snippet, `getObjKeyMap1` does that. In the second, I though the OP would understand that we can avoid as if we specify it in the parameter. I guess your form looks much neater. I'd rather edit the answer to do that. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I meant something like `.reduce<T>(...)`. I believe this is the intended way? Either way, it will still work :) I was just asking a question that I wasn't sure of

Comment: Ah, where was my mind. :) Though, for some reason, it does not work that easily, see here: https://tsplay.dev/DWKA8N I tried casting `Object.keys(obj) as [keyof T]`, no avail.